# How to add and compare members in a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate `is_multi(M)`, defined as:

- every element of `M` has the form `X / N`, where `X` is an atom, and `N` is an integer greater than 0;
- `M` does not contain two elements with the same atom, for what

  ```
  is_multi([]).
  is_multi([a / 2, b / 2]).
  ```

  are satisfied, but

  ```
  is_multi([a, b/2]).
  is_multi([a/0, b/2]).
  is_multi([a/2, 2/4])
  is_multi([a/2, b/3, a/2])
  is_multi([a/3, b/-4, c/1])
  ```

  are not.

Here's what I have written so far:

```
is_multi(M) :- M = [].
is_multi(M) :-
    M = [Head|Tail],
    Head = X/N,
    integer(N),
    N > 0,
    is_multi(Tail).
```

But it does not compare two elements if with the same atom. For example, `is_multi([a/2, a/3])` is not satisfied. I got stuck for one day with this; could somebody give me some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can simplify your code considerably by moving some of your unifications from the body to the head.

```
is_multi([]).
is_multi([X/N|Tail]) :-
  integer(N), N > 0,
  is_multi(Tail).
```

Cleaning it up reveals one thing you're not doing here which is in your spec is checking that `X` is an atom. Fix by adding `atom(X)` to the body.

OK, so this takes care of the basic form, but doesn't ensure that the atoms do not repeat. The simplest thing to do would be to split this into two checks, one that checks that each item is well-formed, and one that checks that the list is well-formed. In fact, I would be inclined to use `maplist/2` with a predicate that checks a single element. But all you really *have* to do is something like this:

```
is_valid([]).
is_valid([X/_|T]) :- is_valid(T), \+ memberchk(X/_, T).
```

This just says that the empty list is valid, and if the tail is valid, a list is valid if X over something doesn't occur in the tail.

If that's all you wanted, stop reading there. If you want to refactor, this is how I would approach it:

```
well_formed(X/N) :- atom(X), integer(N), N > 0.

no_repeating_numerators([]).
no_repeating_numerators([X/_|T]) :- no_repeating_numerators(T), \+ memberchk(X/_, T).

is_multi(L) :- maplist(well_formed, L), no_repeating_numerators(L).
```

Comment: I have another question. When I input a goal: is_multi([a/-2]), it produce error. It cannot distinguish negative number correctly.

Comment: It's because of the priorities of `-/2` and `'/'/2`. You can solve it by writing `is_multi([a/(-2)]).`

Comment: Yes, when I wirte is_multi([a/(-2)]), it's true. But the input format doesn't meet the requirements. I will try to modify the code to meet the requirement. Thanks for your timely answer!

Comment: You could try using `op` to change the priority of `-`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete Daniel's instructive answer (+1 by me), I want to showcase how your task could be solved by means of some library predicates:

```
is_multi(L) :-
    forall(select(E, L, R),
           (E = A/N, atom(A), integer(N), N > 0, \+memberchk(A/_, R))).
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works and is clear. I'am a new prolog learner. I just know several simple built-in predicates for lists. I am very glad to learn new things from you. I need to learn more to write clear and efficient codes. Thank you again for your generous help.